# Change Table name from 'Table S 1' to 'Table S1'

Tags: tables

I used the following command to name my tables in the supplementary file. A question is how can I remove the space in 'Table S 1', so that it becomes 'Table S1'?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

    \begin{document}

\renewcommand{\tablename}{Table S}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Remove the space in 'Table S 1', so that it becomes 'Table S1'}
\begin{tabular*}
\hline
    &   p.adjusted  &   Gene Ratio  \\ \hline
TBA &   3.28E-04    &   12/89   \\
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper way to do this should not be to change the *table name* but the *table number*. Replace `\renewcommand{\tablename}{Table S}` with

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}
```

If you change the appearance of the regular table numbers, then the following code retains that look and just adds an S, which might or might not be what you want.

```
\let\oldthetable\thetable
\renewcommand{\thetable}{S\oldthetable}
```

Changing the table number also affects `\ref`, giving S1, while changing the table name gives just the number 1.

---

Another method: Replace `\renewcommand{\tablename}{Table S}` with

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Table S\@gobble}
\makeatother
```

The command `\@gobble` removes the next token (which in this case is the space).

---

A problem with @samcarters version is that if the caption is longer than one line the space is stretched somewhat, and the negative space doesn't account for that, leaving a small gap between S and 1 (negative space in red, `\@gobble` in black).
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want that the “S” also appears in cross references, the correct way is to add it to `\thetable`:

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}
```

would do good in `article`, but it would not be good in `book`. For a “class independent” solution, add

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
```

to your set of packages and

```
\preto\thetable{S}
```

in the settings section of the preamble.

If you don't need the “S” in cross references, you can use the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{addS}{#1 S#2}
\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=addS}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{Remove the space in 'Table S 1', so that it becomes 'Table S1'}

\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\hline
    &   p.adjusted  &   Gene Ratio  \\ \hline
TBA &   3.28E-04    &   12/89   \\
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a negative space of the size of a space:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\tablename}{Table S\hskip-\the\fontdimen2\font\space }
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Remove the space in 'Table S 1', so that it becomes 'Table S1'}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{lcc}
\hline
    &   p.adjusted  &   Gene Ratio  \\ \hline
TBA &   3.28E-04    &   12/89   \\
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]