# How can I give the table number?

Tags: tables, numbering

I am writing my PhD thesis in overleaf and, the firt table in my thesis appears in Chapter 2. After generating the code, Overleaf numbers it as Table 2.1. But I only want to name it as Table 1. Someone can help me to solve that problem? Thanks.

Comment: The numbering scheme is set by you document class or eventually, a style you load in the preamble of the document. You have to provide an MWE so that we can see how to help you.

Comment: Welcome to TeXstackexchange. Please  add a  minimal working example (  something starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` ) to make it easier for who want  to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `chngnctr` package.

```
% tabcaprob.tex % SE 517296 caption without chapter number

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter} % table numbers independent of chapter numbers
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\chapter{Two}
\begin{table}
\centering
A Table
\caption{A table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

For what the `chngcntr` package does read the manual (`> texdoc chngcntr`). It would have been most helpful if you had provided an MWE that exhibited your problem instead of us trying to invent one. GOM

Comment: It works!!! Thanks a lot, Peter!!!

Answer (score -1):

This should give you a head start

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{addS}{#1 S#2}
\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=addS}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{Remove the space in 'Table S 1', so that it becomes 'Table S1'}

\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\hline
    &   p.adjusted  &   Gene Ratio  \\ \hline
TBA &   3.28E-04    &   12/89   \\
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

All thanks to @egreg  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/305341/197451